# azure issue token api returning Access denied due to missing subscription key

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to call bing text to speech azure services but i keep getting this error on getting the access token , although the subscription key is provided

```
function requestAudio(text,lang)
{
    nameLanguage = "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-GB, Susan, Apollo)";
    language = lang;
    textToSpeak = text;
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: tokenURL,
        data: 
        {  
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'xxxxxxf8cc34d08b646de1bc54c950d'
        }
    }).done(function(data) 
    { 
        token = data.access_token;
        sendAudioRequest();
    });
}
```

The error exactly from fiddler is

```
{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making requests to an API." }
```

and the url i am calling is

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken
```

Comment: Related posts - [API management URL is giving Missing subscription key Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51519687/465053)] & [Azure Api management Is it possible to disable Subscription Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51376248/465053)

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you have to set those in the header, not in the body.

```
beforeSend: function(request) {
  request.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", 'xxxxxxf8cc34d08b646de1bc54c950d');
},
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712546.aspx