# Azure Api management Is it possible to disable Subscription Key

Tags: azure-api-management

Is it a must that Subscription Key sent as part of the request when call through API Managment? is there a way to disable this option?

Comment: Related post - [How to disable subscription key in Azure API Managment with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56081563/465053)

Comment: How to solve the problem without disabling the subscription key - [API management URL is giving Missing subscription key Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51519687/465053)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new product and uncheck "Require subscription" in its settings. Any API added to such product will be callable without a key, i.e. anonymously.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did not think the answer is true - but I tested it and yes, you can call APIs linked to a product where "requires subscription" is unchecked without subscription key; now after I removed the product I still can call the API w/o subscription key - let's wait, how long this persists

Comment: I would not rely on this behavior this is a bug and will be fixed. By design APIs have to belong to an open product to be callable anonymously. Why did you remove the product?

Comment: I just wanted so see if it works - I no not want to have this behavior at all.

Comment: @KaiWalter, Is it a bug or a feature ? :D means is it still there or not..

Comment: Can anyone comment on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76286528/how-to-prevent-azure-apim-primary-key-not-change/76288125#76288125

Answer (score 0):

if you already have an API created and binded to your product, you need to do this.

1. Remove the Subscription Required option from your product.
2. go to the APIs section, select your existing API and from the Settings tab, you can remove the checkbox "subscription Required".

[image]